# Calling C++ from C in a freestanding way

Tags: c++, c

I have a kernel attempt written in C++, and I was wondering about porting it to x86_64 UEFI, but the EFI bootloader, that uses the GNU-efi lib, must be written in C.

How can I jump to the main kernel function from C? Using `extern C` all the way makes the use of the C++ characteristics impossible, maybe some assembly code could be used, or I could make the bootloader call an ELF file that would be the main kernel with an ELF loader. Are this solutions viable?

Comment: `extern "C" void kernel_main() { ... }`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not exactly. Declaration and definition need to be separated in that case.

Comment: @TheDude It's more the general idea that's important. And that it doesn't have to be more complicated than that. Furthermore, if there is no declaration when the definition is made, then it's needed there too.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you really should have actually understood what `extern C` does before asking this. If it just meant 'start acting like a C compiler everywhere', why would it even exist in C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Using `extern C` all the way makes the use of the C++ characteristics impossible

It doesn't. There are no problems to write `extern "C"` in the header and compile your functions with a C++ compiler and use all kinds of C++ features in a separate translation unit.

You just need to avoid the C++ name mangling for the C++ implementation of your entry function. That's what `extern "C"` does, if you use it for the function declaration.

---

Here's a small example:

#### `kernel.h`

```
extern "C" void main_entry_point();
```

#### `kernel.cpp`

```
#include "kernel.h"

void main_entry_point() {
    // use std::string, std::vector, etc.
}
```

#### `bootloader.c`

```
#include "kernel.h"

// call main_entry_point()
main_entry_point();
```